# How to change default collation for any charset in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to change the default collations listed by `SHOW CHARACTER SET`?

For `utf8` I need to change it to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Or is there any switch to enforce the `_unicode_ci` over `_general_ci` for any UTF8xx charsets?

Comment: You might prefer `utf8_unicode_520_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is futile.  Any user can explicitly state what collation to use, thereby defeating the 'default'.

A better solution is to upgrade to MySQL 8.0.  It defaults to `utf8mb4` and (I think) `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

mb4 is useful for Emoji and Chinese.

0900 comes from Unicode 9.0, which is newer than 5.20, which is newer than 4.0, which you are suggesting.

Comment: How do `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` compare to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci`?

Comment: The standard, at least according to the standards committee, gets better.  9.0 is better than 5.20 is better than 4.0 is better than "general_ci".  I do not know the details.  Just use the latest one you can.